# Shorten variables in python

Tags: python

I am trying to shorten my variable so it is less than 79 Characters. How should i go about doing this?

```
movies = [force_awakens, new_hope, rogue_one, last_jedi, empire, return_of_the_jedi]
```

Comment: Variable name length shouldn't matter. What exactly are you trying to do? BTW, there are more Star Wars movies

Comment: Im afraid I dont really understand what you want to do. How would you reduce the length of the variable if it needs to contain a certain amount of elements?

Comment: @cricket_007 No, there aren't.

Comment: Of all the style "rules", line length is the least important.  If you're more comfortable with longer lines than you are with splitting statements along multiple lines, then do it.  Your linter should have a place either in your code or a separate configuration file for you to change these settings

Comment: If you want to shorten the line, just take advantage of the implicit line continuation inside `[...]` and break the line after each comma.

Comment: @chepner There's 6 elements here. There are 8 movies outside of Rouge One...

Comment: @cricket_007 Nope, no Star Wars movies were made between 1983 and 2015. *None*. (la la la i cant hear you)

Answer (score 0):

You can either shorten the variable to less than 79 characters, or break it into multiple lines using parentheses.

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

*You can check out the PEP-8 style guide [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).*

However, if all you really want is to shorten the variable, you can try choosing a smaller name for the variable, or by removing the spaces after each comma. The current length of the line is 84, and removing commas will bring it down to exactly 79. This will make the code a bit uglier, but it will do the job for you.

I hope this helps.